# Extracting codes with optional special characters from a string using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm tying to extract the header and a 2 or 3 digit ISO 639 code from a string.

The general format of a valid string is:

`header + <special char> + <2 or 3 digit code> + (<special char>forced)`

The last section `<special character>forced` is optional and may or may not be present but if present `forced` must be preceded with a special character (like `.` or `_` or `-`) for it to be a considered a valid string.

Examples of valid strings where the header and language code (`eng`) to be extracted are:

```
name.eng
name-eng
name(eng)
name(fri)_eng
name(fri)(eng)
name.eng.forced
name(eng).forced
name.(eng).forced
name.fri.eng.forced
name(fri).eng.forced
name.(fri).eng_forced
name-fri-eng.forced
name_(fri)_eng.forced
name(fri)_eng.forced
name(friday)_eng_forced
name(fri)(eng).forced
```

The one check here is if the language code has a `)` after it then it must have a `(` before it. This is not critical but would be nice if the regex can check for it.

Examples of invalid strings are:

```
nameeng
nameeng.forced
name.eng).forced
name(fri)eng.forced
name(friday).engforced
name(fri)(eng)forced
```

What I came up with to check this is:

`(.*)([._\-(])([a-z][a-z][a-z]|[a-z][a-z])((?<=\(...)\))?(.forced)?`

I'm also trying for the non critical lookback to check for the `(` before the language code if it has a `)` after the code. This again isn't critical but not the core issue I'm facing.

The issue is that the header (and consequently the language code) is incorrect for some of the valid names because I think the expression is too greedy (I'm using C#, no way to turn off greedy for all operands). I've tried the right to left option but that didn't seem to work either after rearranging the expression.

Is it possible to achieve what I need from a Regex in C#?

Comment: Try `^(.*?)(?:[._-]|(\())([a-z]{2,3})(?(2)\)|)(?:[_\W]forced)?$`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgVgNZ/1)

Comment: Should 'fri' just be ignored?

Comment: `Fri` `(fri)` `Friday` etc are part of the header which need to be retained

Comment: Or, `^(.*?)(?=[\W_])[._-]?(\()?([a-z]{2,3})(?(2)\)|)(?:[_\W]forced)?$`. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgVgNZ/2).

Comment: Wow, that's almost perfect, just with `name.(eng).forced` it's missing the `.` before `(eng)` for the header which should be `name.`.

Comment: So, the special chars should be part of the first capturing group?

Comment: Only if present before `.eng.` or `(eng)` etc section. All the rest are working perfectly as expected, just `name.(eng).forced` is missing the `.` after the name in this example because `(eng)` is the language section. This one `name._eng_forced` is is parsed correctly, just with the `(eng)` is missing the `.` with the name.

Comment: If it can't be done go ahead and post the solution, I'll accept it. I not able improve your solution.

Comment: How is regex going to know that `nameeng` is a failure? Is the header always `name`?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan There is `if` in regex.

Comment: @BladeMight if `what`?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan if `group` e.g. matched or not.

Comment: @BladeMight ...that is my point, what EXACTLY is a group. What is it made of. is it "name" literally?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Take a look at `Wiktor Stribiżew` [example](https://regex101.com/r/QgVgNZ/2), 1st group matches `any` word, not exaclty "name", and so on it matches the special character, and `if` it is `(` then match the `)` additionally. Also see that `nameeng` in his example is not matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880315/extracting-codes-with-optional-special-characters-from-a-string-using-regex-in-c/52882273#comment92674482_52880315) since it turned out to be helpful:

```
^(.*?[._-]?)(?=[\W_])[._-]?(\()?([a-z]{2,3})(?(2)\)|)(?:[_\W]forced)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgVgNZ/6).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?[._-]?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, other than newline, as few as possible, and then an optional `.`, `_` or `-`
- `(?=[\W_])[._-]?(\()?` - the next char must be a non-alphanumeric char (due to the `(?=[\W_])` posititve lookahead), then an optional `.`, `-` or `_` is matched and then an optional `(` that is captured into Group 2
- `([a-z]{2,3})` - 2 or 3 lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?(2)\)|)` - a conditional construct: if Group 2 matched, match a `)`, else match an empty string
- `(?:[_\W]forced)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[_\W]` - any non-alphanumeric char
  - `forced` - a substring
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Just an idea: what if you try to match an optional `.` at the end of the Group 1 pattern? See https://regex101.com/r/QgVgNZ/5

Comment: Excellent, that works, an infact you gave me an idea, since there are three possible separation special characters `.` `-` and `_` if you use `^(.*?[._-]?)` for the 1st group it should meet every possible outcome and works like a charm. Please update your answer and with this modification it's the perfect solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I find that your supposition that `nameeng` is invalid speaks to a lack of clarity of definitions of what is a header. The following will work with the success conditions. Note use `IgnorePatternWhiteSpace` to allow multiple lines in the pattern shown below.

```
^
(?<Header>\w+)
[.\-\(\)_]*
(?<Code1>\w+)
[.\-\(\)_]*
(?<Code2>\w*)
[.\-\(\)_]*
(?<IsForced>forced)?
```

Comment: The Header is the string leading upto the language code. name is just an example and it can be anything with any characters.

Comment: @rboy so if there is no delimeter, the header is the string text except for the last three alphabetic digits. Correct? Also is `nameengforced` a valid item?

Comment: `nameengforced` is not valid since there needs to be a delimiter between the header, in this case `name`, the language code, in this case `eng` and the optional suffix `forced`. If there is no language code found then it's invalid.